# Typescript: “not assignable to parameter of type never” error

Tags: typescript

I got this code:

```
blockingFiles: []; //this is on the class


//this is inside a function of the class
this.blockingFiles = [];
this.blockingFiles.push({file: blockingFile, id: fileId});
```

But I'm getting an error on `file` and `id` inside the object I push into the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring your `blockingFiles` as an empty array, you don't really specify the type of the array elements, that why you get the error.

One solution is to define the Interface of your object (the one that contains "file" and "id" keys) and then declare your `blockingFiles` variable as an array of that object.

You could do something like this:

```
interface IBlockingFiles {
    file: string; // Replace the type here if it make sense to your code
    id: string; // Replace the type here if it make sense to your code
}

blockingFiles: IBlockingFiles[];
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the first line for `object[]` instead of `[]` and it worked fine, however I'll make a class for the `BlockingFile` to make the code tidier.